# Andre Norton's "Witch World" reading order

Tags: suggested-order, andre-norton, witch-world

Does any one know if there is a suggested order, other than chronological - by the published date, for reading Andre Norton's "Witch World" series?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe it is usually recommended to read it in chronological order, [this web site](http://www.xenite.org/witch-world/booklist.html) has a lot of information about what is in which book and the ordering to read it in.

Answer (score 0):

There is well researched and comprehensive site [here](http://elwher.wikidot.com/reading-order.)

It offers information on both a publication order as well as an (in-universe) chronological ordering but no specific advice on which would be preferable

Comment: Please provide a summary of that website's opinion. We discourage link-only answers. I'll check back and flag it for deletion unless this occurs.

Comment: @JohnO - I've cleared up the wording.